# Does the degrees of freedom depend on whether the variable is continous or dummy variable?

Tags: categorical-data, sample-size, continuous-data, degrees-of-freedom

In my dataset there is a lot of multicollinearity between the independent variables, therefore it is not possible for me to include them all in the same regression (especially because I have a small sample size). However, my supervisor said that if I categorize some of the variables I might be able to use more independent variables in the same regression.

Why is this? Does it affect the degrees of freedom? Or what is the reason?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you take continuous independent variables and slice them into categories, you don't save degrees of freedom. The more categories you split into, the *more* degrees of freedom you lose.

Worse, you bias your results - the fewer categories, the worse it is.

Numerous posts here on Cross Validated advise against this practice.

Comment: so it would be a bad idea to split age into categories?

Comment: Certainly in relation to the issue posed in this question (where lack of error d.f. is the major problem) . If you're not in that situation you may have a different situation / a new question, but I am quite sure that a question similar to what you asked there has already been asked; I'd suggest trying a few carefully chosen searches first. As a general principle you'd want to have a very good reason to split a variable rather than analyze it as a continuous variable (though I am also not suggesting that you should necessarily seek to fit a linear relationship with it).